# Javascript parse HTML and find elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parsing

Note: I'm running it on chrome console!

I'm having trouble to get elements after parsing a html with jQuery

```js
var ar = document.getElementsByClassName("row")[4].getElementsByClassName("well result-box nomargin");
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  try {
    var html = ar[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[2].getAttribute("href");
    $.ajax({
      url: html,
      success: function(result) {
        var resultHTML = $.parseHTML(result);
        // Here the HTML is parsed
      }
    });
  } catch {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

The problem is happening now, when I try to get it in the parsed HTML

```
.getElementsByClassName("well result-box nomargin")[0].getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[1].getAttribute("href").split("family/")[1];
```

I tried `$.find` with `$.attr` but it's not working.

ajax result: https://hastebin.com/arelirobap.xml

Comment: Could you show the complete JS. The two samples don't seem to be related. We also need to see the actual HTML response to the AJAX request. Also note that you cannot select by multiple classes in `getElementsByClassName()`, so you're going to have issues with that

Comment: you get the element before `ajax` executed, so it won't read. try to loop after `ajax` load.

Comment: @GilangRizkie It looks like OP is getting a list of hrefs to then parse the result of, so the 2nd bit of code would go in the `//Here the HTML is parsed` part - but just guessing.

Comment: Please show the return from the ajax call so we can confirm that you're attempting to get to access it correctly. BTW, If you're using `jQuery` all those `getElementByX` / `getAttribute` calls can be simplified.

Comment: if you have multiple class then you should probably use `document.querySelector()`

Comment: try to remove `ajax` and append the result as html element.

Comment: As noted by Rory and Aria, *"well result-box nomargin"* is not **A** class name.  It is multiple.  `getElementsByClassName` expects a single class.

Comment: I don't have a document just a parsed HTML from jQuery

Comment: `querySelector()` can be called off of any Element, not just `document`. @Superzinho

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple classes if you specify them in the right order with jquery selector (). Example: `$('.class1 .class2').html()`